# Speed when using babel plugin in esbuild

Tags: babel-loader, esbuild

If I use the babel plug-in in esbuild, do I use only the babel, not the esbuild? Or do I use the babel only for the parts I need?
It's much faster to use the babel plug-in in esbuild than just using babel

esbuild, babel plungin